# SilverStripe: Loop If Statement

Tags: loops, if-statement, silverstripe, singlepage

I'm building a single page portfolio with SilverStripe.

So far I am able to loop through my sites and all $Title[s] and $Content[s] are visible in one `<div>`. Now I want to attach a certain CSS-class if the current page (which is looped) is named "Contact".

Something like:

```
//Pseudocode:
<loop start>
if ($Title == 'Contact') <div class="a"></div> else <div class="b"></div>
<loop end>
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: You should add that as an answer and mark your problem solved :-). And be sure to mention your SS version in the future as there are some major changes between 2.x and 3.x, for example in the template engine.

Comment: SS 3.0. I can answer this in a few hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<% if $Title == "Contact" %>
     // Do something ...
<% end_if %>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try a custom getter method such as :

```
function DivClassName() {
  return $this->Title == 'Contact'?'a':'b';
}
```

and use the following in your template.

```
<div class="$DivClassName"></div>
```

keeps the logic out of your templates :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if Title = "Contact" %>
    <div class="a"></div>
<% else %>
    <div class="b"></div>
<% end_if %>
```

Comment: Please supply a little detail. Code alone is rarely enough.